# Highcharts master detail chart zooming in/out

Tags: highcharts

In Highcharts master details chart, every time we draw a brush both the ends get reset. I am trying to achieve something like in highstocks where we can adjust the left and right extremes independently.

Similarly I would like to add handles to brush as it is in Highstocks. So ideally I am trying to replicate Highstocks navigator just using highStocks. As we do not have HighStocks license.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: You can use renderer to draw handles, attach events to them and make it work the way you want. Always you can contact Highsoft team, they may suggest some discount if you don't want Highstock, just Navigator. At least it's worth to try.

Comment: What is a renderer ? Do you by any chance have some sample code for this. please

Comment: It's renderer for Highcharts. See [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer). There is a couple of examples.

Comment: Appreciate the help !! I look into it. God bless you. :)